# Tracking from specific video using QCAR

Tags: android, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

I am developing an android application which receiving the video stream from a server. I want to use QCAR SDK to track the Frame Marker in the video. However, it seems that QCAR can only work on the video from camera device. How can I use QCAR to do the AR with the specific video instead of camera video? Or is any other SDK can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QCAR can only use the live camera feed in v1.5. The video goes directly to the tracker without any hooks for developer intervention or redirection from a video source.

This feature has been requested on the wish list.

You may be able to do it with the [Metaio UnifeyeMobile SDK](http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/). It is more configurable in that way - but it can be quite expensive (unless you are ok with the limitations of the free version).

Comment: Thank you! 
Metaio UnifeyeMobile SDK offers the method to change the image source. I will try it if it suitable for network live streaming.

Comment: I can do that with the Metaio SDK function setImage. But it's not available for free version...Is there any other method to do this?